# C# API - Calling ASync Task from another class

Tags: c#, api, rest

Hope you are well, I'm doing some testing with the google API. My knowledge in PHP for APIs is fairly good, but I am struggling with doing this in C#. My goal is to:

Create "JourneyPlanner" class
Inside that call an API query to find distance between two postcodes
Print the distance

Fairly simple within PHP but struggling to find a similar approach in C#. I can run the call fine from the Main method but when I try to implement my new class, that is when I have some issues.

My class is fairly simple:

```
    public class JourneyDistance
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public async static Task GetPostCodeDistance()
        {
            string postCodeOne = "NR116BN";
            string postCodeTwo = "PE129JE";
            string url;

            url = $"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins={postCodeOne}&destinations={postCodeTwo}&mode=driving&key=APIKEY";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var o = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
            Console.WriteLine(o);
            string child1 = (string)o["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["text"];
            Console.WriteLine(child1);
        }
    }
```

I've tried a few things in the Main but I just cannot simply run the method in question, my reasoning behind this is I'll want to display and run this API call across the system at some point, so need to be able to call this method whenever I need to query two postcodes.

```
    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JourneyDistance journeyDistance = new JourneyDistance();
            //await journeyDistance.GetPostCodeDistance();

            //journeyDistance.GetPostCodeDistance();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Because `GetPostCodeDistance` is an asynchronous method, it returns a `Task` when the first `await` is hit, yielding control back to the caller.

This `Task` will complete once `GetPostCodeDistance` has finished processing, but you need to wait for it to complete, or else your app will likely exit prematurely.

In your `Main` method you can do this:

```
journeyDistance.GetPostCodeDistance().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Which blocks the thread until the `Task` has completed.

Generally you should avoid blocking threads when calling asynchronous methods, but the top level `Main` method is one exception to this rule.

If you are using C#7.1+ you can also make your `Main` method async:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    JourneyDistance journeyDistance = new JourneyDistance();
    await journeyDistance.GetPostCodeDistance();
}
```

Although this is simply syntactic sugar for:

```
private static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    JourneyDistance journeyDistance = new JourneyDistance();
    await journeyDistance.GetPostCodeDistance();
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
    => MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```